# Does it required a slugfield's must be unique in django?

Tags: python, django, slug

im using slugfield in django model's and i've set slugfield to be unique for a reason so that my post should be unique, my slug include's a combination of title and it's object primary key

my slugfield's are generating a slug's as an example like:

> slug url : whats-your-favourite-character-from-the-defenders-1

and the number at the end of my slug represent's primary key ' as you see primary key in my slug which already make's an url unique , so does it make sense that i should use unique attribute in slugfield !

because my problem is when i update my existed object it throws an error 
IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: polls_question.id

Answer (score 0):

Making slug unique **ensures** that it's unique in database so you can rely on it with no worries in your python/sql code. So it does make sense and that is best practice in general.

Concerning IntegrityError you need to provide more details. I'm using such fields with no problems.

Comment: ofcourse it would be great without any worries , but what about when some user edit the title as it would also overwrite the slug , i created a method which slug is generated according to title.

Comment: I just don't see the problem, to be honest. Do you use your own slugfield implementation? If so, I bet you should try smth like https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-autoslug

Comment: it's fine , i was able to work with it ' acutally i was getting an unique contraint failed error everytime my save method run's it's because i was calling super(Question, self).save(self, *args, **kwargs) before my condtion's  in save method ' but then i removed that line and it went well' thank;s anyways